# Initializing struct in C, best practice

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm getting a compile time error during initialization of the members structure in this code. 
What can be some other methods to initialize the below array structure.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_FUNC_MEMBERS 100
#define MAX_FUNC_DESC_STR 50

typedef struct member_struct {
    double degree;
    double coefficient;
} member;

typedef struct function_struct{
    member members[MAX_FUNC_MEMBERS];
    char *description;
} *function;

function malloc_function() {
    return (function) malloc(sizeof(struct function_struct));
}

double compute_function(function f, double x) {
    return 0.0;
}

int main(void) {
    // f1 = x^2
    function f;
    f->members = {
        [0] = {2.0, 1.0},
        [1] = {1.0, 1.0}
    };
    f->description = "x squared";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `f->members` initialization.

Comment: What's the best practice for this is very subjective. Personally I would never use designated initializers for arrays, because... it doesn't make much sense to do so. If you have an array where you need to treat every array member as a special case for whatever reason, you must add comments on each line anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, your program would also segfault even if it compiled, however, since you're assigning data to `*f` without it being allocated.

There are a couple of solutions possible for you. The most straightforward would probably be to simply allocate the `function` struct on the stack instead, but that would require you to either modify its `typedef` not to be a pointer, or using the struct name directly. I'll go with the later for this example:

```
struct function_struct fbuf = {
    .members = {
        [0] = {2.0, 1.0},
        [1] = {1.0, 1.0}
    },
    .description = "x squared",
};
function f = &fbuf;
```

Another would be to initialize the members one by one, manually:

```
f = malloc(sizeof(*f)):
f->members[0].degree = 2.0;
f->members[0].coefficient = 1.0;
f->members[0].degree = 1.0;
f->members[0].coefficient = 1.0;
f->description = "x squared";
```

A third might be to use a compound literal:

```
f = &(struct function_struct) {
    .members = {
        [0] = {2.0, 1.0},
        [1] = {1.0, 1.0},
    },
    .description = "apa",
};
```

That last one does pretty much the same as the first one, only that `fbuf` is anonymous.

You can also combine the second and third, if you want the memory of the struct to be allocated on the heap, rather than on the stack:

```
f = malloc(sizeof(*f)):
*f = (struct function_struct) {
    .members = {
        [0] = {2.0, 1.0},
        [1] = {1.0, 1.0},
    },
    .description = "apa",
};
```

As for your "best practice" aspect, I don't think either is inherently better or worse than any other, but they do *differ* in some aspects:

- The third and fourth, using compound literals, require latter versions of C, so if you're aiming to be compliant with ancient C compilers, they are a bad idea. This should be a rare issue these days, however.
- The first and third allocate the data on the stack, while the second and fourth allocate the data on the heap. This is different, rather than better or worse, so pick whichever suits your scenario.
- Depending on the compiler, the second example *may* be faster, since it doesn't touch the 98 members that are left unused. You'd have to be initializing a lot of `function` structs in a very tight loop for that to be a problem, however. :)

Comment: Well just one more thing I wanted to know that whether this type of initialization works with ANSI C.

Comment: That depends on which ANSI C. The third and fourth examples won't work with ANSI C89, but that's ancient history by now. None of them should have any problems with ANSI C99 or ANSI C11.

Comment: And also what's the error in the f->members declaration I did. I continue to get the error even after allocating space for function declaration.

Comment: The problem is that that syntax isn't valid, quite simply. Compound initializers are only valid syntax at the site of the definition of a variable, not in arbitrary assignments. In the latter case, you need to use compound literals instead, as in my third and fourth examples. However, compound literals aren't supported for arrays (that's not exactly true, but it's true enough for this case), so that wouldn't work in your case, either.

Comment: Thank you again! You were very descriptive in your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `char *` but you haven't allocated memory for the string it will point to.

You could do something like:

```
function f = malloc(sizeof(function));
const char *desc = "x squared";
f->description = malloc(strlen(desc) + 1);
strcpy(f->description, desc);
```

To verify that it works:

```
fprintf(stderr, "description: %s\n", f->description);
```

Comment: That is actually not his problem, however, since he isn't doing an `strcpy`. There shouldn't be any problem with simply assigning a static string literal to it.